# No error stack trace being displayed with Python 2.7 on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, stack-trace, python-2.5

I recently shifted from Python runtime version 2.5 to 2.7 while developing a web app on Google App Engine, and I notice that in many cases when a script runs into an error, the stack trace isn't shown any more. With runtime Python 2.5 this is the stack trace in the browser:

[image: Error tracebacks on Python 2.5]

(The *Python 2.7.2* on the top right is because I have that version of python installed on my machine.) Changing the runtime to `python27` does this to the traceback for the same error:

[image: No error tracebacks on Python 2.7]

The 2.7 runtime works fine otherwise, however, and I am also able to use 2.7-specific libraries. I've noticed that errors in the python code that cause this behaviour have nothing to do with the capabilities of the runtime version. I think this happens at least with faulty GQL syntax in the python script, but also with other errors.

For the time being I'm reverting to 2.5 whenever I get the second picture, fixing the problem, then going back to 2.7, but pretty soon this won't be possible because most of my code will rely on 2.7 functionality. **So how do I get the nice detailed error traceback of Python 2.5 to show on the 2.7 runtime as well?**

Comment: you could always catch the error and then print it out (very bad idea - but hey.... life isnt perfect)

Comment: The traceback will be printed to the logs (on the dev server, this is stdout of the server process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks there was an open issue with the SDK: http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/issues/detail?id=34.

However, based on the last comment, it seems that the change has not been incorporated into the latest build. Testing this out on my machine (OSX with SDK 1.7.0.129), the behavior is same as described above and in comment 4 of the issue.

If someone from GAE team can weigh in on this, would be great.

Comment: There seems to be a difference in behavior - if an uncaught exception is being raised by the app, the stacktrace will display. If you are missing something like a package you are trying to call, you'll just get Error500...